# String match angularjs/javascript max 2 characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

i've got a function that matches all letters after a space. I mean;

```
"this is my string" --> tims
```

just doing this:

```
$scope.getLetters = function(str) {
            var matches = str.match(/\b(\w)/g);
            var acronym = matches.join('');
            return acronym;
        }
```

where `str` of course is the string that i pass from the html. It works pretty well but i would extract max 2 characters. So if the string is

```
"this is my string"
```

i would `ti` only and not the others. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slice` before `join`:

```
var str = "this is my string";
str.match(/\b\w/g).slice(0,2).join('')
//=> "ti"
```